# Simple Apex code snippet not behaving as expected

Tags: apex, loop, code, conditional

```
Integer delay = 1;
for(Integer i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    System.debug('Print '+i);
    Long sTime = System.now().getTime();   
    while ( (System.now().getTime()/1000 - sTime/1000) < delay){}
}
```

When I executed the above code in anonymous window and checked the log, it is printing only 4 and 5. not sure why it is skipping 1,2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will print all the numbers. But as the log size is high so it is skipping some part of lines in that start. You can find **METHOD_ENTRY *** Skipped xxxx bytes of detailed log** at the starting of the log file which means some line are getting skipped because of the log size.

You can change the log level of Apex to Debug and remaining to none so the it only generates small log file so you can see all the values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keep the Log Level for Apex Code as `DEBUG` and rest all to `ERROR`.

```
Integer delay = 1;
for(Integer i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    System.debug('Print '+i);
    Long sTime = System.now().getTime();
    while ( (System.now().getTime()/1000 - sTime/1000) < delay){}
}
```

[image]